# Warning Access denied for user 'user_example'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: linux, mariadb, centos

I've had some issues with an application and deleted it, also deleted the user and the database.

And I'm having an issue when opening websites (too many connections..)

So I check the logs and see

> [Warning] Access denied for user 'user_example'@'localhost' (using
> password: YES)

user_example is the app I've deleted and I think it's still making many requests and causing the too many connections error and (Error establishing a database connection)

What should I do? how can I know where is it connecting from? and stop these connections?

thanks.

Comment: Did you reboot your computer? The application could still be running, even if it is deinstalled...

Comment: I did, its a linux server and hosting multiple apps and websites. Is there a way to know which file trying to access the database? or how it is trying to access it ?